# Not translate select options in Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-translate, zend-form-select

I have a big form with a lot of select elements with a lot of options each one. All translations work well (labels, descriptions, errors), but i don't want to translate the options shown in the select element.

The official guide says nothing about it, please check the following link: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.select

However here it says: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiselect "If a translation adapter is registered with the form and/or element, option values will be translated for display purposes. "

I can't remove the translation adapter, so my question is: Is it possible to ignore this element options?

Looking forward to your news.
BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Zend_Form_Element_Multi have this:

```
if ($this->translatorIsDisabled()) {
    return false;
}
```

And there exist this method on Zend_Form_Element

```
public function setDisableTranslator($flag)
{
    $this->_translatorDisabled = (bool) $flag;
    return $this;
}
```

So I've created a method that extends Zend_Form_Element_Select and call:

```
$this->setDisableTranslator(true);
```

That solved my question.

Comment: I used this once but it did a little bit more than I wished for.
It also disables field label translation and error translation.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$this->setTranslator(new Zend_Translate_Adapter_Array(array()));` at beginning of your form. This will override default translator, and because new one is empty then it will not translate anything.

Comment: Hi Volvox, i can't remove the adapter because the validation errors are not translated, and I need to show the errors in multilingual because the form it's complicated. 

I can translate labels, descriptions and placeholder without problems with one specific function, but i do not how to do that with the errors messages...You'd know how to do it?